# NumberFormatException- Invalid Int

Tags: java, android, numberformatexception

I am trying to add a bunch of drawable references to a list and I need to change the number in the drawable reference as each one refers to a different item. I have attempted as follows:

```
for(int x=69;x<222;x++){
            urls.add(x,Integer.parseInt("R.drawable.item"+(x+1)+"_lock");
        }
```

and while running it produces a `NumberFormatException` error: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "R.drawable.item70_lock"`

Is this the correct way to go about what I am attempting to do or is there a different way?

Comment: Integer.parseInt() tries to get an Integer value, that is written in a string. Integer.parseInt("123") hence will return 123. Alltho the R.drawable.item123 is nothing else than a unique Integer ID for the drawable, Integer.parseInt("R.drawable.item123") will return in that exception, because "R.drawable.item123" is not a number.

Comment: Why do you think the *text* `"R.drawable.item70_lock"` is a number?

Answer (score 0):

get resource ids dynamically:

```
for(int x=69;x<222;x++){
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier("item" + (x+1) + "_lock", "drawable", getPackageName());
    if(id != 0)
        urls.add(x, id);
}
```

Comment: This is an anti-pattern, resources should not be accessed this way.

Comment: link on the anti-pattern please

Comment: Like an article? I have none, I am speaking from experience. This will work fine at first, but introduce some flavors or Gradle generation logic and it will become unstable. Resources in Android are static and should be accessed with the static, generated identifiers from the `R` class.

Comment: what kind of "gradle-generation logic"? how the flovors can break this approach? give me an example or remove your down vote please

Comment: Gradle resource gwnerating tasks. And flavors can end up removing/adding some resources, which will result in the code unpredictably skipping some of them (and lint will not warn about it, as it would in case of R identifiers becoming unavailable forbthe given flavor). Your code will work, but it should be considered hacky and should not be used in production code.

Comment: whatever who removes/adds the resouces, this method returns actual `id` or `0`. plus, i'm not saying this is a good way, but it's the only way when you need to access the ids dinamically. your answear is simply 'no', my answer solves the problem

Comment: Returning 0 (or rather handling it as an invalid output) is exactly what I mean by unpredictability - debugging it will be hard when something goes wrong. As a side note, it is pretty obvious that op misunderstood the idea of Android resources. Your answer will let them run their code, but will not improve their understanding of how things work in Android.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how Android resources work :)

First, resource pointer is actually a constant int, not a `String`. `R.drawable.item_1_lock` is a field in the auto-generated class `R`.

Second, `Integer.parseInt()` is used to change a number-like String into an actual number primitive type. So if you call it with a `String` param "1", what you get is a int with value 1.

The problem here is that the `String` you pass is not number-like. It can not be turned into a number, so an exception is thrown.

Lastly, you can not generate a resource pointer in runtime. They are auto-generated and prone to change, so you should not generate them like above. Create an `int[]`, put the possible resources in it and get it with the `x` you iterate on :-)

Comment: Is it a misconception then that the reference `R.drawable.XXX` is just referring to the filename XXX?

Comment: R.drawable.XXX is a static field in the class called `R`, not a String identifier :-)

Comment: And it is referring the resource called XXX, but you can not access it the way you tried to. Not with a String, you need to use the identifiers generated in the R class (which are auto-generated ints)

Comment: Ok so therefore if I understand correctly what I am trying to do is not possible then if the identifiers are auto-generated links.

Comment: It is possible per se, see answer by @Oleg. But you should not do it this way in Android. Map the int identifiers to values, do not try to generate resource ids yourself :-)